# `which` not showing path for script in ~/bin

Tags: bash, macos

Out of curiosity I called `which myscript.sh` for a script I have under `~/bin/myscript.sh` (in macOS's bash). I can execute the script with no problems from any directory without giving its full path. `~/bin` is on my `PATH` and the script has executable flags set, `ls -l` outputs `-rwxr-xr-x`.

I would have expected `which` to show me the script's full path, but it didn't output anything.

Is this intended behaviour or is something odd happening here?

Comment: what does `echo $PATH` and `type myscript.sh` say?

Comment: Related: [Why not use “which”? What to use then? - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/117037)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you add a literal tilde `~` to your `PATH`, instead of the actual path to your home directory. Rewriting `~` into `/home/youruser` is the job of the shell, not of the tool or filesystem. If you e.g. quote the `"~"`, this rewrite doesn't happen and other tools like `which` get confused.

Here's information on this issue from the [shellcheck wiki](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2147):

---

### Literal tilde in PATH works poorly across programs.

#### Problematic code:

```sh
PATH="$PATH:~/bin"
```

#### Correct code:

```sh
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

#### Rationale:

Having literal `~` in PATH is a bad idea. Bash handles it, but nothing else does.

This means that even if you're always using Bash, you should avoid it because any invoked program that relies on PATH will effectively ignore those entries.

For example, `make` may say `foo: Command not found` even though `foo` works fine from the shell and Make and Bash both use the same PATH. You'll get similar messages from any non-bash scripts invoked, and `whereis` will come up empty.

Use `$HOME` or full path instead.

Comment: awesome answer! I changed `~` to `$HOME` now everything works as expected :D thank you!